# Using libraries with SAS University Edition

Tags: sas

This is a novice question. I'm starting with SAS using SAS University Edition, and I'm trying to create a new folder. The code that I'm using is:

`libname bee 'C:\JL\B'; run;`

It gives me the note: "Library bee does not exist".

And when I try to see what is in the library using the code `proc contents data = INNOVA._all_; run;`, it gives me the error: "Library BEE does not exist" even though the word bee appears as recommended by SAS Studio when I am writing it.

Does anyone know the answer? I am using the SAS Studio of SAS University Edition with Virtual Box.

Comment: You put your files in the myfolders folder you set up during installation. Then you access them in the location `/folders/myfolders/.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch this video: [Accessing Your Existing Data for SAS University Edition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFuaaavKvSE)

The virtual machine you are using is running Linux. If you followed the setup instructions, you would have set a shared folder to somewhere on your hard drive. Within the virtual machine, you're going to refer to the root of that folder as /folders/myfolders. Outside of the virtual machine, it would be whatever Windows folder you set.